# Snails strange behaviour

Tags: snails

My aquarium snail was not well, I thought so. In the morning he stopped moving , so I thought that he was dead so I took it out and kept it in another glass jar with water . Then he started moving and climbing its wall .
About four five days ago I found four snails dead in my aquarium . I am now afraid that if the alive one dies then it can affect other fishes as well.

What should I do , put it back into the water or let it remain there?